# Accessing the application.conf properties from java class with Play! 2.0

Tags: java, configuration, playframework, playframework-2.0

I want to add an object to the Global scope, and in order to construct it I need to pass it a path to a file.
I don't want to hard code the file path in the source, and so I want to get that path from the application.conf.

The problem is that I don't know how to access these properties from the java class.
I tried this:

```
Configuration.root().getString("file.path")
```

But it ends with a *NullPointerException*.

Am I wrong in assuming that there's a global Configuration instance that I can use?
Thanks.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Try `Play.application().configuration().getString("your.key")`

As noted in the comment (nico_ekito), please use `play.Play` and not `play.api.Play`. `play.api.Play` is for scala controllers (see comment by Marcus biesior Biesioroff)

Additionally, play uses https://github.com/typesafehub/config under the hood so it can also provide some insights.

Comment: `Play.application()` doesn't exist anymore :/

Comment: Be careful with the import, do you use `play.Play` and not `play.api.Play` ?

Comment: as Cyril N mentioned Play.application() does not exist!

Comment: @nightograph can you elaborate? I just created a brand new 2.0 java project, added the following lines 'String key = Play.application().configuration().getString("key");
    return ok(index.render(key));' and added a key in conf file. I get the text value in the conf file.

Comment: my `Play.application().configuration().getString("key")` is still available too. @nightograph and Cyril, could you explain ?

Comment: @MarcusbiesiorBiesioroff It was my mistake, I had play.api.Play imported instead of play.Play! sorry for the confusion

Comment: @nightograph, that's good news I was afraid that's something worse :) be careful, every class starting with `play.api` is for using in Scala controllers.

Comment: @MarcusbiesiorBiesioroff ohh!!! that's great tip Marcus. thanks so much! I was so confused why the framework would have 2 Play objects. Better naming would had been nicer Play.scala and play.java for example

Comment: I modified the answer, so hopefully, it will not cause confusion in the future :) - Kudos to nico_ekito who clarified it first

Comment: Play.application() is now deprecated. So update to the answer would be nice.

Comment: @LasithaYapa I would check i.am.michiel's reply below and see if it helps. I haven't used Play in years now.

Comment: If you are using latest version this may not work. Check Saeed's response

Comment: This approach is deprecated, use dependency injection instead.

Comment: Still works in 2.5.  I have no idea why a single config read suddenly needs dependency injection. :/

Comment: Since 2.6.0 com.typesafe.config.Config should be used via dependency injection.

Comment: Starting from version 2.5 this approach is deprecated. Please use play.Application class which should be injected and then application.config().getString("your.property.here")

Answer (score 55):

Even if it seems simple, here is the **scala** way to get properties from configuration file :

**Play 2.0 and 2.1** :

```
import play.api.Play.current
...
Play.application.configuration.getString("your.key")
```

**Play 2.2 and +**

```
import play.api.Play.current
...
current.configuration.getString("your.key")
```

**Using Typesafe config**

```
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
...
ConfigFactory.load().getString("your.key");
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm using java though and not scala

Comment: Why can't you use `current`?

Comment: `Play.current.configuration.getString("your.key")` seems to be the way in Play 2.2.2

Answer (score 39):

From `Play 2.4 and +` it is better to use dependency injection to access Configurations:

```
import play.Configuration;
import javax.inject.Inject;


@Inject
private Configuration configuration;

...

String value = configuration.getString("your.key");
```

Comment: Since Play 2.6.0 Configuration is deprecated and you need to inject com.typesafe.config.Config instead.

Answer (score 12):

Since Play 2 uses the Typesafe config library, I accessed my vars in application.conf like this :

```
ConfigFactory.load().getString("my.var");
```

Comment: Yep! This variant is way better than others. It works in filters too (before Global object initialized).

Comment: Beware that this will load the default configuration file, but if you loaded other files afterwards (for example, application.dev.conf) in Global, it won't be taken into account. Found out the hard way :(

Answer (score 3):

In the play java is:

```
import play.Play;
...
Play.application().configuration().getString("key")
```

Answer (score 2):

Use as following (Tested in Play 1.2.5)

```
${play.configuration.getProperty('my.var')}
```

where my.var should be specified in application.conf file

Comment: i was looking for that +1

Comment: for exactly what I was looking for +1

Answer (score 1):

As a reference to access it from the template (for play < 2)

```
play.configuration['your.key']
```

Answer (score 1):

As folks have mentioned, `Play.application.configuration` no longer exists.

In Play Scala 2.3.x, to read a value from `conf/application.conf`, you can do the following:

```
import play.api.Play.current
...
current.configuration.getString("key")
```

Answer (score 0):

In Play 1.2.x

```
import play.Play;
...


String version  = Play.configuration.getProperty("application.version.number", "1.1.1");
```

where the second parameter is the default value

Answer (score 0):

Import this

```
import com.typesafe.config.Config;
```

and write the below lines

```
private Config config;
this.config = ConfigProvider.config();
String value = this.config.getString("fieldFromConfigFile");
```

Answer (score 0):

`import play.Play;
String myVal = Play.configuration.getProperty("your.key").toString();`

i use this in my app and it works

Dont forget to import play.Play. Hope it'll gives you help

Answer (score 0):

Starting from version 2.5 please use play.Application class which should be injected and then
 `application.config().getString("your.property.here")`

Answer (score 0):

For Java Playframework:

In **Application.conf**, you can put something like that:

> email="example@gmail.com.pe"

some class:

> import play.Play;
>
> String email = Play.application().configuration().getString("key")  // key ->email