# Is play framework 2 a good framework to do java?

Tags: playframework-2.0

since I had a absolutely fantastic experience with play 1.2, I convinced my new client to port to play from their in-house built MVC framework, Now I'm starting to port their java framework to play-2 and I'm not having a good time. My personal feeling is that Play is not as convenient for java development anymore and these are my reasons/feelings. I think that Play has taken a turn towards Scala and has lost java as a focus. for example the ease of query parameter binding and template loading is not there anymore, you have to specify the query params in the route file?? really?? sometimes even object names  dont make sense, I spent a lot of time figuring out how to get a simple value from the config file and a simple Play.application().configuration().getString("key"); does not work, only to realize after a day that I had play.api.Play imported as play.Play OR the function chain WS.url("url").get().get().asJson(); makes me very uncomfortable, get.get?? is anyone else feeling the same or is it a complete taste thing?

Comment: It's `matter of taste` I prefer the P2 with Java over the P1. There are leaks in docs, but the Community still fixes it and most recent version can be found at https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki . SO examples... well I don't know what to say. Answers can be good or wrong, but it's not a framework's guilt. In general I don't think the P2 is _worse_, maybe you should ask more technical questions?

Comment: with the examples that you could not run were those for the scala or java based framework (only asking because its a good thing to knock out first)?

Comment: I'm developing in java so those are the examples i looked at e.g     Play.current.configuration.getString("db.driver");

Comment: Hm, but the only answer at Stack I found has `scala` tag, hasn't it? http://stackoverflow.com/a/9858011/1066240 , the Java sample is also available and is also tagged as `java` http://stackoverflow.com/a/9849100/1066240

Comment: Please define what you think is "a good framework to do Java". Otherwise we can't answer your question.

Comment: a good framework is well documented, has a large number of java developers who are using it and willing to support, it is easy to be integrated with common IDEs like eclipse (as far as I know, you can't run the debugger inside eclipse yet), and makes sense, in my start with play 2, I could not figure out how to get values from application.conf even examples here don't work - i could not access the request object from the action controller (badly documented) - for the query parameters to pass you have to edit the route file????? just want to know it is personal dislike or others feel the same!

Comment: @Li-o another example, I just realized that my Play.application().configuration().getString("key"); is not working because i had imported play.api.Play instead of play.Play - yes, it was my mistake but this is very obvious bad naming!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that [play 1](https://github.com/playframework/play) is still supported, so you do not really need to switch to [play 2](https://github.com/playframework/Play20) unless you want to. However, the play framework code is open source, so even if it was no longer supported you could just fork their repo and maintain a version of it for yourself.

Have you tried to go through their [example apps](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/tree/master/samples/java)? That (while looking through their source code) is usually a good place to start.

Comment: Looking for a simple way to get a form parameter from the request for last hour! play framework 1 was as easy as params.get("key")
the fact that in play2, even getting a simple value from form is unclear, leaves no doubt that Play framework2 is not "good" framework to work with in java *good framework, is a framework that things make sense, operatios like getting a parameter from request is easy!