# Error in Loading custom conf file from application.conf

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.3

I'm using play-2.3. I want to load my custom config file through `application.conf`. But could not load it.

```
 conf /
          application.conf
          mycustom.prop
```

I'm including mycustom.prop in application.conf as follow.

```
   include file("CAB.prop") 
     or 
    include "mycustom.prop"
    or 
     include "mycustom"
```

None of above worked.

**mycustum.prop:**

```
myappIp=x.x.x.x
myappport=1234
```

In code when I'm trying to accessing myAppIp, it gives me `NullPointerException`

**MyGlobal.java**

```
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
...
    String ip = ConfigFactory.load().getString("myAppIp"); // this line throws NullPointerException
```

I'm not sure, either problem is in loading `mycustom.prop` or while geting its values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

Turns out they only support a few file extensions: https://github.com/typesafehub/config#rationale-for-supported-file-formats. I tested various files, and only `.properties`, `.conf` and `.json` files are picked up by `include`. Any other file types are silently ignored.

---

*(the following is not the problem, although the Play docs state this, the underlying library accepts the format mentioned in the question - kept here for legacy purposes)*

From the [docs](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Configuration#Include-syntax):

> An include statement consists of the unquoted string include and a single quoted string immediately following it.

So it should be

```
include "mycustom.prop"
```

Comment: I did that, but no success.

Comment: @MuneebNasir Are you sure that the way you attempt to load the config is correct? I can't remember ever seeing it like that. Where are you trying to read it?

Comment: include file("CAB.prop"), If you are pointing to this way, I got that from some link( I lost track of that). i don't even sure about it. 
But the way you are referring, I tried this as well. but no success

Comment: @MuneebNasir No, I mean in your `MyGlobal.java`

Comment: yes, here is a link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9844568/accessing-the-application-conf-properties-from-java-class-with-play-2-0

Comment: If you know some-other way, please let me know. As I mentioned, I'm not sure where the problem is, either in loading conf, or in the way I'm getting value.

Comment: @MuneebNasir Digging around a bit, I get the impression that only `.conf`, `.properties` and `.json` files are supported. See https://github.com/typesafehub/config#rationale-for-supported-file-formats

Comment: great - Thank you @gpgekko.

Answer (score 0):

You could try including the `application.conf` in the `mycustom.prop` and then start activator with with `-Dconfig.resource` or `-Dconfig.file`.

Your `mycustom.prop`:

```
include "application.conf"
# much configuration follows
```

And start with `activator -Dconfig.resource=mycustom.prop` if your config file is on the classpath (e.g. in the config folder) - or with `activator -Dconfig.file=/opt/conf/mycustom.prop` if you want to specify a path.

Comment: is there no way to add another file in application.conf?